# LocationManager and iBeacon: How to count the current number of monitoring regions

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

LocationManager is used to monitor iBeacon regions.

Method: _locationManager.monitoredRegions.count returns 2
But I get an error:

```
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 5.)"
```

It seems that this error is returned when more than 20 zones are monitored..

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager monitoringDidFailForRegion:(CLRegion *)region withError:(NSError *)error
```

How to remove regions from the location manager

Answer (score 1):

call `[_locationManager stopMonitoringRegion:myRegion];` to remove a region :)

and `[_locationManager monitoredRegions].count` works for counting (remember monitoredRegions is a set and duplicates are filtered out)